# How to send messages to multiple users?

Tags: java, sockets

Essentially I have a basic Java Socket server as you can see below. It allows multiple users to connect and when they send a message to it, it returns it back. However I was wondering how I could edit it so if a user sends a message to it, rather than just sending it back it sends it to everyone connected? So a basic chat server. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class ClientWorker implements Runnable {
  private Socket client;
  private JTextArea textArea;

  ClientWorker(Socket client, JTextArea textArea) {
   this.client = client;
   this.textArea = textArea;   
  }

  public void run(){
    String line;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    try{
      in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
      out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("in or out failed");
      System.exit(-1);
    }

    while(true){
      try{
        line = in.readLine();
//Send data back to client
         out.println(line);
         textArea.append(line);
       } catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println("Read failed");
         System.exit(-1);
       }
    }
  }
}

class SocketThrdServer extends JFrame{

   JLabel label = new JLabel("Text received over socket:");
   JPanel panel;
   JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
   ServerSocket server = null;

   SocketThrdServer(){ //Begin Constructor
     panel = new JPanel();
     panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     panel.setBackground(Color.white);
     getContentPane().add(panel);
     panel.add("North", label);
     panel.add("Center", textArea);
   } //End Constructor

  public void listenSocket(){
    try{
      server = new ServerSocket(4444); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Could not listen on port 4444");
      System.exit(-1);
    }
    while(true){
      ClientWorker w;
      try{
        w = new ClientWorker(server.accept(), textArea);
        Thread t = new Thread(w);
        t.start();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Accept failed: 4444");
        System.exit(-1);
      }
    }
  }

  protected void finalize(){
//Objects created in run method are finalized when 
//program terminates and thread exits
     try{
        server.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not close socket");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
        SocketThrdServer frame = new SocketThrdServer();
    frame.setTitle("Server Program");
        WindowListener l = new WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                }
        };
        frame.addWindowListener(l);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.listenSocket();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a little modification by providing a holder to hold all the clients. Can be a List implementation. Then you could write a broadcast method and invoke that instead of `out.println()`. In that method you would be doing the similar thing by the way.

Moreover, you should look into [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) to implement this effectively, plus you will get a good understanding of a design pattern too. Another pattern that would be helpful here is, [Mediator Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/mediator-pattern.html).

Comment: Sorry if this sounds rude but how would I go about doing this? I'm rather new to Java and i'm building a Server to use with another project, this is the last bit of it and I really want to get it finished :)

Comment: Without knowing your overall design, I wouldn't be able to suggest you anything exact. So, have a look here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/c_sharp_remoting.aspx . Its a chat application example based on Observer Pattern using .NET. Will definitely provide you a good hint.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll take a look!. Thats the program in its entirety ha ha

Answer (score 0):

Every time you create a new `ClientWorker` in `listenSocket`, keep a reference to the client in a list that all the client workers have access to (whether global or - preferably - passed into them when they're created). When a client receives a message, it can cycle through the list and send the message back out to each worker. You will need to be careful when adding/removing/iterating through this list, since you're going to have a lot of threads running that could all try and access it at the same time.

Also, for correctness your access to Swing components (such as `textArea.append` in `ClientWorker`) should be done from the EDT rather than from the client's thread. See the javadocs for [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)).